# Is this user method parameter well named?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method to check if a User can edit either a post or a comment on my Rails application. Because a user can own both types of entities, I decided to make this method take either of them as a parameter `post_or_comment`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def can_edit?(post_or_comment)
    post_or_comment.user == self || self.admin?
  end
end
```

Is this a good practice to ambiguously take any object like this as a parameter, and does the name I chose for the parameter make sense?

I am not interested in a sophisticated user-role handler like CanCan, as I am learning and would rather keep it simple.

Comment: I'd have two separate tests as two methods, then a third that wraps the two as a convenience. That'd allow better granularity when testing. Because it's an admin role, being very explicit what the admin can do is good, especially if you intend to share the code with others. Taking any variable type might bite you inadvertently in the future so checking to see that it's what you intend is smart, again since security is involved. Parameter names like `post_or_comment` are fine, but if the code accepts a parameter that isn't either you probably want to know and deal with it correctly.

Comment: Could you give an example of this if/when you get a chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's understood that within your schema a post is a type of comment or vice-versa then it's not really all that confusing to express it in the form of one or the other with the implication that it applies equally to both types.

Generally it's best to avoid overly restricting things unless you have a very good reason. There's ways of turning your very specific method into one that probably works most of the time, and if not it's because you're passing it an unowned thing:

```
def can_edit?(thing)
  # Admin can edit anything.
  return true if (admin?)

  case (thing)
  when User
    # Users can edit themselves
    thing === self
  else
    if (thing.respond_to?(:user))
      # If the owner matches.
      thing.user === self
    else
      # Don't really know, so say no by default.
      false
    end
  end
end
```

The worst case failure state for this code is that it says "no". Now you can pass in arbitrary things that may or may not have a `user` property and it will work as expected. For other special cases you can add another `when` to the main `case`.

Comment: Thank you, I found this very useful (didn't know about `respond_to?`). Question: is there a reason why you're using triple equality instead of `==`?

Comment: @RolandoMurillo Both might work here but you'd have to test to be sure. I've used `===` in the past to assert that they're equivalent records, based on `id`, as ActiveRecord uses that to compare two models.